# What are good research methods to discover why people don’t stick in a product and learn how to improve engagement?

Tags: user-behavior, user-research, research, user-engagement

I have a question in respect to how to improve user engagement and stickiness with a product:

**Context**: Our product is one of the pages inside a website. We installed Hotjar and google analytics in our product and we noticed that people aren’t staying in our product page.

**Observation:** People navigate and explore the website but when they click in our product page from the top nav they spend a few seconds in our main page, sometimes not even scroll down and then they leave.

**Problem:** So either people aren’t finding value in our main page, or the content is not well presented or something is going on but we don’t know why.

**Question**: So we know there is a problem (at least now we know!) but now we need to discover what is causing it. **What would be a good research method for this? What would be a good method to discover why people aren’t sticking or even interacting with your product? What would you do to discover why and how to improve this?**

My first thoughts were we could do:

- a [five second test](https://usabilityhub.com/guides/five-second-testing) for our main page?
- or usability test? --> but we’ve done this before.
- check competitors and try to see what can we improve in respect to content?

Any recommendations?

Thank you in advance,

Comment: What did your usability test look like? What results did you get?

Comment: They said they understood it and that they would use it in the future. We obviously had lots of usability improvements to make which we did but nothing related to the home page not being clear or anything related. Which is very confusing. That is why I'm wondering if a usability test would be a good option to measure this or not. Because we need a method focused on getting information related to if they find the product valuable or not or first impressions.

Comment: Have you been able to confirm through analytics or other sources that the traffic that is coming to your main page is a match for the target audience? I'm wondering if there's a mismatch - driving the wrong persona to the page, and they're not finding value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments:

> > What did your usability test look like?

> "They said they understood it..."

Sounds like a survey (getting people's opinion), not a usability test. When it comes to usability, don't ask—watch.

Instead usability explores how easily people can perform particular tasks on the page. Find out what are your company objectives you like people to achieve accessing the page? For example, if your product is BMI calculator, one objective is: determine your BMI. Ask people to do that and watch how hard or easy it is for them to do it.

Marketing surveys—also important—discover what people want/need, Usability tests help you design a process to help them do it.

---

Do all you outlined:

- A [Five Second Test](https://usabilityhub.com/guides/five-second-testing) for your main page,
- A usability test, of course test usability—ease of accomplishing task, reaching goal, taking action—and
- Research competition.

Add to that:

- Start with a robust marketing survey to discover: 1) your target market, and 2) their wants and needs related to your area of expertise, and
- Once you have a proposed design hire one to three marketing and usability experts to evaluate it.